# Database values retrieval error - regarding

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am new to android, I am trying to retrieve values from a sqlite database based on the listview values. I tried to retrieve values using string variable. I can do this if I directly substitute the value in the place of variable.

Following this I post my codes kindly help me to sort out this.

DBhelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public SQLiteDatabase DB;
public String DBPath;
public static String DBName = "VERIFY ME1.sqlite3";
public static final int version = '1';
public static Context currentContext;
public static String tableName = "FORM2";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, version);
    currentContext = context;
    DBPath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases";
    createDatabase();
    Oninsert(DB);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void createDatabase() {
    boolean dbExists = checkDbExists();

    if (dbExists) {
        // do nothing
    } 
    else {
        DB = currentContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, 0, null);
        DB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +tableName +" (AppNo VARCHAR, AppName VARCHAR," +
                " Area VARCHAR, FHcode INT(3));");


    }}

private boolean checkDbExists() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DBPath + DBName;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        // database does't exist yet.

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
private void Oninsert(SQLiteDatabase dB2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DB = currentContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, 0, null);
    DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            tableName +
            " Values ('M001','shumi','India',250);");
    DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            tableName +
            " Values ('C002','sarah','India',251);");
    DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            tableName +
            " Values ('D003','Lavya','USA',252);");
    DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            tableName +
            " Values ('V004','Avi','EU',253);");
    DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            tableName +
            " Values ('T005','Shenoi','Bangla',254);");
    DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            tableName +
            " Values ('L006','Lamha','Australia',255);");

    DB.close();
}

}
```

ListActivity.java

```
public class login2 extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

private static final login2 ListActivity = null;
private static final AdapterView<?> parent = null;
private static int mPosition = 0;
private static final long id = 0;
private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

private String tableName = DBHelper.tableName;
private SQLiteDatabase newDB;
private String AppName1,ApplID,FHcode,Area;




/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    openAndQueryDatabase();

    displayResultList();


}
private void displayResultList() {


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

}



private String openAndQueryDatabase() {
    try {
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +tableName +"", null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                AppName1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AppName"));

                    results.add(AppName1 );


                }while (c.moveToNext());
            } 
        }   
        c.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } finally {
        //if (newDB == null) 
        //  newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
            //newDB.close();
    }
    return AppName1;

        }



    public void onClick(View arg0) {


      login2 det = (login2)ListActivity;

        det.onItemClick(parent, arg0, mPosition, id);

    }


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String data=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //showMessage("Successfully", data);

    if (data != null ) {    
    try {
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor c1 = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT AppNo, AppName, FHcode, Area FROM "
                +tableName +" where AppName ="+data+"" ,null);


        if (c1 != null ) {   

            if  (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                      ApplID= c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("AppNo"));
                      String AppName =c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("AppName"));    
                 Area = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("Area"));
                 FHcode  =c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("FHcode"));


                 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), form.class);

                    //Create a bundle object
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();

                    //Inserts a String value into the mapping of this Bundle
                    b.putString("AppName", AppName.toString());
                    b.putString("Apprefno", ApplID.toString());
                    b.putString("FHcode", FHcode.toString());
                    b.putString("Area", Area.toString());


                    //Add the bundle to the intent.
                    intent.putExtras(b);

                    //start the DisplayActivity
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                 while (c1.moveToNext());

            }
            }   
    }


    catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } finally {
        //if (newDB == null) 
            //newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
            newDB.close();
    }
  }
}       

public void showMessage (String title, String message)
{
      Builder builder=new Builder(this);
      builder.setCancelable(true);
      builder.setTitle(title);
      builder.setMessage(message);
      builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have taken this column as an integer FHcode INT(3)

and trying to fetch values as an string that is wrong

**c1.getString**(c1.getColumnIndex("FHcode")

change to **c1.getInt****(c1.getColumnIndex("FHcode")

Comment: I tried that , still its show error like " Could not create or Open the database" Please help .. Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have skype id come there i will check your code..my id is : akash_yadav30